# Linear combination of wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, superposition

What does plus or minus sign indicate in linear combination of wave functions?

Answer (score 5):

It represents relative phases of the wave functions you are adding together.

Let's say $\psi=\psi_1-\psi_2$. This can be written as

$$\psi=e^{-i \cdot 0}\psi_1+e^{-i\cdot \pi}\psi_2$$

So you can see the two terms have different phases (assuming $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ don't encode any other differing phase information).

You will typically hear that multiplying your wave function by a number of modulus $1$ doesn't change the probabilities encoded by that wave function. However, doing this to individual terms in a superposition *can* make a difference. In other words, overall phase doesn't matter (you can just rotate your frame to get back to what you started with), but relative phase does matter.